# DHTMLX SCHEDULER custom light box

Tags: dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I am using custom light box, for recurring events everything is working fine the problem is when we edit a recurring event we should get dialog asking for "Edit Series", "Edit Occurance" that dialog is not appearing. 
I have added configs like:

```
  scheduler.config.repeat_precise = true;
  scheduler.config.lightbox_recurring = 'Ask';
```

AM i missing something? 
Moreover I am using unit view that will contain both single and recurring events.

Answer (score 0):

This dialog is a part of the original scheduler.getLightbox method - https://github.com/DHTMLX/scheduler/blob/v4.4.0/codebase/sources/ext/dhtmlxscheduler_recurring.js#L776 .

If you redefine that method - you need to reimplement the dialog as well, here is a code snippet

```
var labels = scheduler.locale.labels; 
dhtmlx.modalbox({
    text: labels.confirm_recurring,
    title: labels.title_confirm_recurring,
    width: "500px",
    position: "middle",
    buttons:[labels.button_edit_series, labels.button_edit_occurrence, labels.icon_cancel],
    callback: function(index) {
        switch(+index) {
            case 0:
                return alert("edit series");
            case 1:
                return alert("edit ocurrence");
            case 2:
                return alert("cancel");
        }
    }
});
```